# Bootstrap - how to increase columns intelligently when the screen get indefinitely large?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I use the classes below for large and extra large screen:

```
col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-sm-12
```

[image]

It creates **3 columns** on **extra large** screen which is great. But the **first problem** is when it comes to **extreme large** screen - it will **always stay** at 3 columns.

How can increase the **numbers of columns** when the screen get larger and indefinitely large?

For instance - depends on the screen size,

```
col-xxl-5
col-xxxl-6
col-xxxxl-7
col-xxxxxl-8
```

While the **second problem** is that you can see that I add the class manually `col-xxxxxl-8` which is not ideal. So, is there any way to do this **intelligently**?

Or maybe [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) can do this better??

This is the [entire code](http://www.bootply.com/5BVmvHzs3x) that I am working on.

Comment: @DavidG any examples please.

Comment: What about https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/06/bootstrap-add-xl-grid-size-option/ ?

Comment: @fen89 isn't the same as the col-xl-* that I am using??

Comment: @teelou yes you're right, you're using the same technique - sorry I was too fast with my reply... I didn't find a solution either until now

Comment: What about treating `.item-grid` like text by setting their display to `inline-block` and setting a `max-width`? Here is a [forked bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zLZAHUdBIT)

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper I don't understand. Cud u please explain a bit more? Wut did u change/ add to the css in the forked bootply?

Comment: I added this CSS: `/** Max-width and inline block approach to columns on XL **/
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .items-grid { text-align: center; font-size: 0; }
  .item-grid { max-width: 600px; float: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; }
}` So for any screen sizes wider than 1600px, text-align `.items-grid' to the center, and then display all the `item-grid` elements as inline-blocks. Set a max-width on them too so they never get too wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of Bootstrap, but I know ZURB's Foundations has the ability to declare larger breakpoints (aka media querises) so you can style your code in xxlarge screens. as noted here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html#changing-the-breakpoints

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0px,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
```

than, you'd be able to use something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 medium-3 xxlarge-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-3 xxlarge-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

keep in mind you have to use the SASS version of foundation.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it seems to be the solution I am looking for! :-)